# twitter4j 4.0.2 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j 4.0.2

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(this.consumerKey);
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(this.consumerSecret);
cb.setOAuthAccessToken(this.accessToken);
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(this.accessTokenSecret);
this.twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

here the error i am getting when i run this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient
    at twitter4j.AlternativeHttpClientImpl.prepareClient(AlternativeHttpClientImpl.java:120)
    at twitter4j.AlternativeHttpClientImpl.getConnection(AlternativeHttpClientImpl.java:60)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:88)
    at twitter4j.AlternativeHttpClientImpl.handleRequest(AlternativeHttpClientImpl.java:104)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:71)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:128)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.verifyCredentials(TwitterImpl.java:545)
```

how to get this working??

Comment: Did you add all the required jar files into application to make it work ?

Comment: yes included twitter4j-core.jar, twitter4j-async.jar, twitter4j-media-support.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the version 4.0.2 at least has a dependency on **okhttp**. This is only true for the **twitter4j-spdy-support** package and not the other in **twitter4j**.

The [pom.xml](http://twitter4j.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-spdy-support/4.0.2-SNAPSHOT/twitter4j-spdy-support-4.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom) has:

```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
         <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.1</version>
     </dependency>
```

If you want to use the **twitter4j-spdy-support** then you need to have the okhttp JAR file(s). If you use maven the running your app with maven will solve the problem.

And the other option is not to use the spdy support and not have it in the classpath.

Comment: i remove twitter4j-spdy-support.jar and all working fine, @toomasr thanks.

Comment: This is great to hear, I'll also edit the answer to include that one solution is not to use spdy support if you don't need to.